location.reload() sends me to previous page in Next.js 14
I have an app that sends user to main page after login.On the main page I have a navbar that displays "Log in" or user's name based on the state of the user's log in status.To refresh the state in the navbar component i call
if (!user) {
    router.push("/main-page");
    location.reload();
  }

in the client component inside the navbar,that holds the state. But after loging in the user is pushed back to the /auth/login page even though he is logged in and i have access to the "user" object.After the user is sent to /auth/login he has to manually navigate to /main-page where the state is finnaly updated,but this makes for terrible user experience.
I am also using next-auth.js , even though i don't think that makes any difference.Anyone know a way to refresh the state withouth router.push() , or another way of reloading the page that dosen't trigger before my api call goes to get the user data?

Why would you refresh the page? after the user is logged in, it's normal to redirect the user, but not need for a refresh.
If you handle this in server side, you can check for login stage and pass the status to your client components (like Navbar). Or if it's handle in client side, then just need to update the state (in a Context or your global state)

I do want the user to be redirected after login,but the state of the navbar after redirecting still remains the same as the user didn't yet log in.So i have to refresh manually to update the state in Navbar,so user is shown.

The only way to resolve this is to call
if (user) {
    router.push("/main-page");
  }

inside the login form component,but I think that is a terrible idea for security.
